# SQL Query how to minus the result from different SQL query? [Sum()'s opposite subtraction]

Tags: python, sql

I have several different SQL query, I pasted two query as below, I want to calculate the value from these different SQL query from different tables, I can sum all the value, but what about minus all the values? Such as `val1-val2-val3-val4`

```
SELECT code, SUM(val)
FROM (
-- query A（table_name_a）, `val1`
SELECT code,
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('111', '222', '333')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END)/
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('444')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END) AS val
        FROM table_name_a
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND date BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code, date
UNION
-- query B(table_name_b), `val2`
SELECT code,
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('111', '222', '333')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END)/
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('444')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END) AS val
       FROM table_name_b
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8) BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code, substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8)
) res
GROUP BY CODE;
```

If I input parameter `'%(code)s', '%(start_date)s' and %(end_date)s'` with '00001' , '20191001' and '20191030', I got result as below

```
    code    val1
1   00001   0.00798752 -- result from query A

    code    val2
1   00001   0.00472937 -- result from query B
```

Now I would like to get the result by 0.00798752 - 0.00472937, I have four value from four different SQL query, can I minus them via only one SQL query?

Comment: Best you post some sample data from both table with your expected output.

Comment: @mkRabbani Hi, I already posted sample data as question, I just want to minus the results from those SQL query, still need more sample data?

Comment: As I seen, you posted only Output data of your query. I am asking for your input data with table structure and then what output you are expecting from them.

Comment: I've already solved my problem by myself. thank you all the same, hahahhaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the value `*-1` that you want to minus, make the value negative, hahahahaha, amazing SQL!!!! I love math and SQL

```
SELECT code, SUM(val)
FROM (
-- query A（table_name_a）, `val1`
SELECT code,
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('111', '222', '333')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END)/
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('444')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END) AS val
        FROM table_name_a
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND date BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code, date
UNION
-- query B(table_name_b), `val2`
SELECT code,
          (sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('111', '222', '333')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END)/
          sum(CASE WHEN remark IN ('444')
                    THEN t.value ELSE 0
                    END)) * -1  AS val  -- let the value * -1
       FROM table_name_b
       WHERE code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8) BETWEEN '%(start_date)s' AND '%(end_date)s'
       GROUP BY code, substr(regexp_replace(date,'-',''),1,8)
) res
GROUP BY CODE;
```